# MATLAB: Does my k-NN classifier works correctly?

Tags: matlab, classification, knn

I am working on a project and I want to use k-NN classification on fisher's iris dataset. I present my k-NN classification MATLAB code below:

```
rng default;

% k-NN classifier

indices = crossvalind('Kfold',species);
cp = classperf(species);

% k = 1
for i = 1:5
    test = (indices == i); 
    train = ~test;
    class = knnclassify(meas(test,:),meas(train,:),species(train,:));
    classperf(cp(:),class,test);
end
fprintf('The k-NN classification error rate for k = 1 is: %f\n', cp.ErrorRate);

fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause

% k = 3
for i = 1:5
    test = (indices == i); 
    train = ~test;
    class = knnclassify(meas(test,:),meas(train,:),species(train,:),3);
    classperf(cp(:),class,test);
end
fprintf('The k-NN classification error rate for k = 3 is: %f\n', cp.ErrorRate);

fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause

% k = 5
for i = 1:5
    test = (indices == i); 
    train = ~test;
    class = knnclassify(meas(test,:),meas(train,:),species(train,:),5);
    classperf(cp(:),class,test);
end
fprintf('The k-NN classification error rate for k = 5 is: %f\n', cp.ErrorRate);

fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause
```

My doubt lies on that the cp.ErrorRate is the same for all k = 1,3,5.

Is this the accept state or should it be different for k = 1,3,5 ?
If so, what do I have to change to my code to accomplish my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation was actually not far from the truth. If you have a look at the  plot of the Iris data set, you will see that the data is really good separable:

[image: 3D scatter plot Fisher's Iris]

So if you pick a data item, you can almost always classify it very precise with 1, 3, and 5 neighbors. The error rate will be very small in these cases. The rate will grow when using a bigger number of neighbors:

[image: error rate KNN]

...but if you try to classify the data using only one feature, especially the one, which cannot separate the data well by its own, the plot will look differently (here I classified data only based on the second feature):

[image: error rate KNN one feature]

**BUT!** First of all you need to correct your code a little bit.

Each time you execute `classperf(cp(:),class,test);` the previous `cp` structure is updated. It's ok as long as you are in the loop through your folds, but when you go to the next experiment for another `K` value, you need to re-initialize the `cp` structure again! Otherwise the results of each next experiment will be biased by the previous statistics.

Have a look at the matrix `cp.CountingMatrix`. It contains `confusion` information about already classified data points, while iterating over the folds. When you call `cp.ErrorRate`, the error is calculated based on this matrix. If you do not re-initialize it after each loop, the statistics for the next experiments are added to results from the previous experiments (I took only 3 rows from the matrix):

```
k = 1; i = 1;

    10     0     0
     0    10     0
     0     0    10

k = 1; i = 2;

    20     0     0
     0    19     0
     0     1    20

k = 1; i = 3;

    30     0     0
     0    28     0
     0     2    30

k = 1; i = 4;

    40     0     0
     0    37     1
     0     3    39

k = 1; i = 5;

    50     0     0
     0    47     3
     0     3    47

k = 3; i = 1;

    60     0     0
     0    57     3
     0     3    57   % is biased by the first experiment
```

Here is my code where you can see the re-initialization of the `cp`:

```
rng default;
load fisheriris;
fold_number = 5;
indices = crossvalind('Kfold',species, fold_number);

val = 1:2:100;

err_arr = [];

for k=val

    cp = classperf(species); %!!! reinitialize the cp-structure

    for i = 1:fold_number
        test = (indices == i); 
        train = ~test;
        class = knnclassify(meas(test,:),meas(train,:),species(train), k);
        %class = knnclassify(meas(test,2),meas(train,2),species(train), k); %to experiment only with the 2nd feature

        classperf(cp,class,test);
    end

    err_arr = [err_arr; cp.ErrorRate];
end    

plot(val, err_arr, 'LineWidth', 2);
grid on;
xlabel('K');
ylabel('ErrorRate');
```